# SQL - using NVL function is throw error ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

This query as below throw error `ORA-06512` :

```
select NVL (an_invc_date, 'S'),
  NVL (an_fixed_invc, 'N'),
  NVL (an_credit_invc, 'N'),
  NVL (cinvoicecountertype, 'A'),
INTO c_bl_invc_date,
  c_fixed_invc,
  c_credit_invc,
  c_gldiv_invcounter
FROM officectl
WHERE co = c_file_company
AND div  = NVL (c_file_stn, c_user_location);
```

Oracle throw error in this line `SELECT NVL (an_invc_date, 'S')`,
I have already check type and size is consistency. `c_bl_invc_date` have declared as `VARCHAR2 (1)`.
May be another place to check ?

Thanks

Comment: The name of column is  an_invc_**date**. So maybe you need DATE there instead of string.

Comment: whats the data type of c_bl_invc_date ? Can you post the full procedure

Comment: Show us your table definition.

Comment: you are trying to capture a date column into a varchar(1) ?

Comment: please post the datatype of `an_fixed_invc, an_credit_invc, cinvoicecountertype`?

Comment: Why you did not put the error message in the question? Why I do need to search what ora-06512 means?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the query, I think the issue is because of the comma(,) at the end of the line 4. Please check and confirm